# Sceneform, Pale 3D model

Tags: android, sceneform, specular

I'm noticing with Sceneform 1.16.0 that sometimes my 3D model (glb) loads and appears pale/lighter (right screenshot), like there's a layer over top of it. Any idea why this could be? This occurs approximately every 35 loads.

[image] [image]

```
        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(context, Uri.parse(uri))
            .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
            .setRegistryId(uri)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by bumping the filament version to 1.7.0

https://github.com/google/filament/releases/tag/v1.7.0